# Taylor/Maclaurin Series vs Taylor/Maclaurin Polynomial

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

For this question, I will use $sin(x)$ as an example. The Maclaurin series for $\sin(x)$ is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{{(-1)}^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$ This gives us a Maclaurin polynomial to represent $\sin(x)$, but is there another way to represent $\sin(x)$ which doesn't give us a polynomial? Is there any case where the Taylor/Maclaurin series gives us a non-polynomial representation for a certain function?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the Taylor/Maclaurin series by definition have to have be a polynomial (perhaps of "infinite degree," since a polynomial is by definition finite in degree but that's another issue). Fourier series of functions can be used as a means of writing functions as a (possibly infinite) sum of sine and cosine terms, and I imagine other series based on different functions can be developed as well. (None come to mind since this isn't something I've looked too deeply into.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to represent $\sin\left(x\right)$ which doesn't use a polynomial (of any degree), but with Maclaurin & Taylor series, due to how they're defined, they will *always* give a "polynomial" (almost always of infinite degree, although polynomials may be defined as only allowing a finite degree, as [Eevee Trainer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/597568/eevee-trainer) commented to the question) representation for any function.

Comment: How else can it be represented?

Comment: @Jondue There are basic trigonometric identities like $\sin\left(x\right) = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\right)$ or $\sin\left(x\right) = \frac{1}{\csc\left(x\right)}$. With complex #'s, [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) of $e^{ix} = cos\left(x\right) + i\sin\left(x\right)$ gives $\sin\left(x\right) = \frac{e^{ix} - cos\left(x\right)}{i}$. As Eevee Trainer stated, you could also use a Fourier type series of functions, with I believe it being possible to use something other than $\sin$ and $\cos$, although it'll likely be more complicated & less useful.